# Async pipe does not show my observable

Tags: angular, angular-observable

In code below page shows before-null-after, but console shows '2'. For some reason page is not updated... What do I do wrong?

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'


@Component({
  template: `before-{{searchResult | async | json}}-after`,
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  searchResult: Observable<String[]>;

  searchTerms = new Subject<String>();

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(['aaaa', 'bbbb']));

    this.searchResult = this.searchTerms
      .switchMap(term => this.http.get('/assets/async.json').map(response => response.json() as String[]));
    this.searchResult.subscribe(next => console.error(next.length));

    this.searchTerms.next('sss');
  }
}
```

"@angular/core": "^4.0.0"

Comment: When you're running `subject.next('sss')` there is no subscription from template

Comment: For example this will work https://plnkr.co/edit/kKNHI7NKWsebWmhl32mx?p=preview and `publishReplay` can also help https://plnkr.co/edit/IOuzGaIcROVnu4fcOhLc?p=preview

Comment: Yes, i understand the problem. I actually run the next() method in code that subscribes to this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(). Is there a way to observe queryParam and show it in template? I want to change the url params as user updates search, then i want to react with result. It works fine, but not during the first page load.

Comment: `publishReplay` doesn't help?

Comment: Thanks, to spot the broblem. I just do not use Observable<String[]> but just String[] member and fill it in subsribe method. It keeps the value till the template is loaded. I liked the code before, but this works....

Comment: Yes, magic, searchTerms = new ReplaySubject<String>(1); seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`searchTerms = new Subject<String>();`

use

`searchTerms = new ReplaySubject<String>(1);`

where the number indicates how many of the already emitted values are cached and emitted when subscribing to this observable

or

`searchTerms = new BehaviorSubject<String>('');`

where the observable always remembers the last emitted value, you have to give an initial value.